# Pandas subplots plotting multiple y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe that looks like this. I need a subplot for each unique Item (book, Table and Chair). The plots should be sorted by Year (Year is also the x-axis).  I need to make use of twiny to have Price on the left and Quantity plotted on the right of each subplot.

I can do this manually for each Item by creating a individual dataframe. So I created a dataframe for Book, then sorted by Year and set Year as index. then create the plot with secondary_y.  But obviously this is long winded. Is there a way to do this from the original dataframe without all the manual processing?

```
    Item  Year Price  Quantity
0   Book  2000    $2        50
1  Table  2000   $33        44
2  Chair  2000   $21        31
3   Book  2001    $3        77
4  Table  2001   $20       500
5  Chair  2001    $2        50
6   Book  2002   $36         7
7  Table  2002  $200        50
8  Chair  2002   $44         5
```

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Why comment, if you are not going to be helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean here, but maybe your can use `groupby()` and then traverse the groups?

Here's a simple example (using pyplot)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline

dicts = []
dicts.append({'item':'book','year':2000,'price':2, 'quantity':50})
dicts.append({'item':'table','year':2000,'price':33, 'quantity':44})
dicts.append({'item':'chair','year':2000,'price':21, 'quantity':31})

dicts.append({'item':'book','year':2001,'price':3, 'quantity':50})
dicts.append({'item':'table','year':2001,'price':20, 'quantity':44})
dicts.append({'item':'chair','year':2001,'price':2, 'quantity':31})

dicts.append({'item':'book','year':2002,'price':36, 'quantity':7})
dicts.append({'item':'table','year':2002,'price':200, 'quantity':50})
dicts.append({'item':'chair','year':2002,'price':44, 'quantity':5})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dicts)

grouped = df.groupby('item')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True)

fig.set_size_inches(15,4)

for i,group_key in enumerate(list(grouped.groups.keys())):
    grouped.get_group(group_key).set_index('year').plot(kind='bar',ax = axes[i])
    axes[i].set_title(group_key,fontsize=15)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I'll give this a go and see how it goes.

Comment: Felipe, your code is very close to what I need, but I am having a couple of issues. 1. The scales of the two y axis values are far apart, so I need to set my own ylim=[]  .  2. I also want to set label for the two y axis.  When I create plots manually, I can acheive this by twinx and set_ylabel for each ax1 and ax2. But I don't get how I can do that within this loop?

Comment: Thanks Felipe, Your answer helped be realise that grouping and looping over the df is an option and now I have managed to achieve what I was look for.

Answer (score 2):

You may find seaborn's factorplot very useful for this:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html

It handles plotting categorised data like yours, saving you the effort of grouping and looping. There are lots of examples at the above link, but hopefully this is close to what you want:

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item': ['Book', 'Table', 'Chair'] * 3,
    'Year': [2000] * 3 + [2001] * 3 + [2002] * 3,
    'Price': [2, 33, 21, 3, 20, 2, 36, 200, 44],
    'Quantity': [50, 44, 31, 77, 500, 50, 7, 50, 5],
})

g = sns.factorplot(data=data, x='Year', y='Price',
                   col='Item', kind='bar', sharey=False)
```

[image: Jupyter output]

If you want to plot both price and quantity (using a secondary y axis), you can use a custom FacetGrid object with map_dataframe. This doesn't seem to play so well with seaborn though; labels, legend, etc need to be added afterwards. I think the preference for their categorical plotting functions is to create more plots rather than use secondary axes (i.e. a second row of plots for quantity).

```
def bar_plot(data, **kwargs):
    ''' Called with each subset of data by 'Item' '''
    ax = plt.gca()
    data[['Year', 'Price', 'Quantity']].plot(
        x='Year', kind='bar', ax=ax, secondary_y='Quantity')

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=data, col='Item', sharey=False)
g.map_dataframe(bar_plot)
```

[image: Combined bars]

Comment: Thanks Simon, this looks good. I will have a play and try to get it to work for what I need.

Comment: Simon, is there a way to have another Y axis when using seaborn? I know secondary_y is an option with matplotlib, but can't seem to find a way to use that in seaborn.  I need to plot the quantity column next to price for each year.

Comment: Updated this with another option - you can use a custom plotting function for each subplot. Under the hood this is really just passing subsets of the data to the plotting function, so Felipe's answer might be more transparent and easier to customise.

Comment: Thanks again Simon, I will look at both options again and hopefully get one to work. I am looking at grouping and looping option now (as suggested by Felipe). The second y axis seems to be causing the most issues. I'll keep at it and will get there in the end.